# Flutter web app has streambuilder works perfectly locally but after deployment on my server on Bluehost it's not working

Tags: flutter, deployment, stream, builder

I have a flutter web App that uses google firebase services all works perfectly locally on android studio, but after deploying it on my server in Bluehost the streambuilder widget stopped working, which should get the data from firestore collection, though other firebase services work like authentication, getting data from firestore but not using streambuilder.
Please, any tip/advice is appreciated.
Below is the code of my streambuilder

```
StreamBuilder(
                initialData: [UserDetailsModel()],
                stream: Globals.refUser.snapshots(),
                builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
                  if (!snapshot.hasData) return const Text('Loading...');
                  return DataTable(
                    dividerThickness: 5,
                    dataRowHeight: 60,
                    showBottomBorder: true,
                    headingTextStyle: const TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.white),
                    headingRowColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith(
                        (states) => Colors.blueGrey),
                    dataRowColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith(
                        (states) => Colors.white),
                    columns: usersFirestoreController.createUserColumns(),
                    rows: usersFirestoreController.getUsersDetails(
                        context, snapshot),
                  );
                }),
```

Comment: Solved the error, it wasn't a stream builder widget issue but it was the expanded widget incorrect implementation the weird thing that it was working locally fine though when published the error persists.